# ggplot in R - divide x axis in two groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, facet

I would like to divide my x axis into two groups. I managed already to make one group using facet but can't make a second one. Here is a picture of what I already have and what I want additionally.
Here is also my command:

```
ggplot(myk.p, aes(x=Group, y=Colonization, fill=MO)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", colour="black") +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000","#7a7a7a","#c0c0c0")) +
    theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"), strip.background =
    element_blank()) + facet_wrap(~Water, switch = "x", scales = "free_x") +
    ggtitle("Root mycorrhization in % (Populus nigra)")
```

[image: Chart]

Example Data.csv:

```
"Group" "Colonization"  "MO"    "Water" "Fertilizer"
"P1"    69,2307692308   "C" "once"  "without"
"P2"    71,8232044199   "F" "once"  "without"
"P3"    82,5174825175   "I" "once"  "without"
"P4"    66,4122137405   "C" "once"  "with"
"P5"    86,013986014    "F" "once"  "with"
"P6"    98,7654320988   "I" "once"  "with"
"P7"    41,9540229885   "C" "twice" "without"
"P8"    65,7894736842   "F" "twice" "without"
"P9"    63,9705882353   "I" "twice" "without"
"P10"   62,5850340136   "C" "twice" "with"
"P11"   87,012987013    "F" "twice" "with"
"P12"   89,696969697    "I" "twice" "with"
```

Comment: If you would like,  you could do `facet_grid` instead of `facet_wrap`, although that will give you a 2x2 plot

Comment: You need to include enough data to make your issue [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Generally, you need to facet by a variable with two levels to get two facets.

Comment: I added a sample csv file.

Comment: How about `facet_wrap(~Water + Fertilizer, switch = "x", scales = "free_x", nrow = 1)`?  It's not exactly what you have, but pretty close.  Adding back some spaces between panels would make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. aosmith: Works perfect. The only problem I now have is that the ordering is wrong. I want to start it from P1,P2,...P12
This is what I got now:

[almost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oh4zH.png)

Comment: The facets are ordered by the levels of the factors.  So if you want `without` to come first you can set levels of the factor: `myk.p$Fertilizer = factor(myk.p$Fertilizer, levels = c("without", "with"))` and rerun the graph code.  As this currently reads this should be a comment, not an answer.  Add in your final code to make this an official answer

Comment: Works fine. Thanks so much.